# Continue on exception

Tags: java, exception

I get a few exceptions when I run my code.
What I want to do is, I want to continue on `FileNotFoundException` and `NullPointerException` and break on any other exception.

How can I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: You should fix your code to eliminate those exceptions.  There is **no** excuse for code which throws `NullPointerException` s.

Comment: Code that throws NullPointerExceptions is unlikely to work correctly at all.

Comment: +1 SLaks: Words of wisdom. Intended NullPointerExceptions are always slower than an if condition.

Comment: SLaks is right, you can catch and ignore file not found (although you should at least inform the user that something untoward happened), but there's virtually no situation where catching and ignoring an `NPE` is valid. Fixing the code to check for nulls is the only good option.

Comment: I will try to handle the NullPointerException. Coz its not my code, it come from a package I am using. But in case of FileNotFoundException, my code breaks. I want it to continue with the loop on this exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {
    stuff()
} catch( NullPointerException e ) {
   // Do nothing... go on
} catch( FileNotFoundException e ) {
   // Do nothing... go on
} catch( Exception e ) {
   // Now.. handle it!
}
```

Comment: Though I think he meant it excactly the other way around?

Comment: Nanne: Me too when I wrote it first, but then I reread the question and it became clear.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but should never ever be used.

Comment: bizclop: Thats me, the mercyless programmer without morale. Of course would I hate everyone who pollutes my code base like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as @daniel suggested, but I have some additional thoughts.

1. You never want to 'do nothing'.  At least log the fact that there was an exception.
2. catching NullPointerExceptions can be dangerous.  They can come from anywhere, not just the code where you expect the exception from.  If you catch and proceed, you might get unintended results if you don't tightly control the code between the try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

multiple catch block to caught exception arised in try block

```
<code>
try{<br/>
// Code that may exception arise.<br/>
}catch(<exception-class1> <parameter1>){<br/>
//User code<br/>
}catch(<exception-class2> <parameter2>){<br/>
//User code<br/>
}catch(<exception-class3> <parameter3>){<br/>
//User code<br/>
}
</code>
```

Source : [Tutorial Data - Exception handling](http://tutorialdata.com/java/exception.html)